# SQL-92 filter result and write for the first row in set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I rarely use SQL but code for filtering, and now I need to fill column in table with sql-92 standart.

There is one table that contains user ids and transaction statuses. So the output table should contain column with a flag if user and transaction was successful with the first try, with multiple tries or unsucsessful at all. The problem that I should not aggregated output by users and leave it "transaction based"!
The rules are:

1. If there is only statuses 200 or 202 for user, it is "successful with first try" at **first** row with that user in table and other rows with that user is Null
2. If user satatuses contains 200 or 202 AND any other statuses, then the user is "successful with multiple tries" at **first** row with that user in table and other rows with that user is Null
3. If user satatuses only other statuses then 200 or 202, then the user is "unsuccessful" at **first** row with that user in table and other rows with that user is Null.

So I should transorm this:

```
id  dt          user_id status_
26  01.01.2020  111     200
12  02.01.2020  112     200
7   03.01.2020  112     202
19  04.01.2020  113     400
87  05.01.2020  113     200
9   06.01.2020  114     400
14  07.01.2020  115     400
1   08.01.2020  115     400
65  09.01.2020  116     202
34  10.01.2020  116     202
```

to this:

```
id  dt          user_id status_   custom_col    
26  01.01.2020  111     200       "Successful with first try"
12  02.01.2020  112     200       "Successful with first try"
7   03.01.2020  112     202       Null
19  04.01.2020  113     400       "Successful with multiple try"
87  05.01.2020  113     200       Null
9   06.01.2020  114     400       "Unsuccessful"
14  07.01.2020  115     400       "Unsuccessful"
1   08.01.2020  115     400       Null
65  09.01.2020  116     202       "Successful with first try"
34  10.01.2020  116     202       Null
```

So what I thought to do, my algorithm:

1. Get each transaction
2. Check if user in this transaction in return of subsequence which corresponds rule 1 or rule 2 or rule 3
3. write only in first row with that user.

So I came only how to fill every row for user, but not only the first:

```
SELECT id, user_id, status_, 
    CASE
        WHEN user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM test t1
                         WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                         (SELECT user_id, status_ FROM test t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t2.status_ > 202))
        THEN 'Successful with first try'
        WHEN user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM test t1
                         WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                         (SELECT user_id, status_ FROM test t2 WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t2.status_ <= 202 ))
        THEN 'Unsuccessful'
        ELSE 'Successful with multiple try'
        END as new_col
FROM test
```

The question is how I can write it only to first row in set? I understand, that I should somehow get TOP 1 id of subset and check if id of transaction with user_id is right id, but my tries end on very deeply nested cases, so I gave in and write here for help :)

Here is schema if you need it:

```
create table test (
    id serial primary key,
    user_id int,
    status_ int,
    some_col text
);

insert into test values (26, 111, 200, 'abs');
insert into test values (12, 112, 200, 'abs');
insert into test values (7, 112, 202, 'abs');
insert into test values (19, 113, 400, 'abs');
insert into test values (87, 113, 200, 'abs');
insert into test values (9, 114, 400, 'abs');
insert into test values (14, 115, 400, 'abs');
insert into test values (1, 115, 400, 'abs');
insert into test values (65, 116, 202, 'abs');
insert into test values (34, 116, 202, 'abs');
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by user_id order by dt) > 1
             then null
             when count(*) filter (where t.status_ not in (200, 202)) over (partition by user_id) = 0
             then 'Successful with first try'
             when count(*) filter (where t.status_ in (200, 202)) over (partition by user_id) > 0
             then 'Successful with multiple tries'
             else 'Unsuccessful'
        end) as custom_col             
from test t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f2e3c7c37287d2f69fcc3e675f9049e3) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

You can express this without window functions as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when id > min_id then null
             when num_not200s = 0 then 'Successful with first try'
             when num_200s > 0 then 'Successful with multiple tries'
             else 'Unsuccessful'
        end) as custom_col
from test t join
     (select user_id, min(id) as min_id,
             sum( case when t.status_ not in (200, 202) then 1 else 0 end) as num_not200s,
             sum( case when t.status_ in (200, 202) then 1 else 0 end) as num_200s
      from test t
      group by user_id
     ) u
     using (user_id)
order by id;
```

This also doesn't use Postgres specific extensions, such as `::` or more modern syntax such as `filter`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, but is it friendly with SQL-92 standard? As I thought window functions came in 2005.

Comment: @Pruntoff . . . What version of Postgres are you using?  All major databases support window functions and have for many years.

Comment: 6.3. It supports. It is hard to explain, but now I have to work with a visual dashboard constructor. Query validates to SQL-92 standard and I have no idea how it sends the query to db (because it is bugged as my life and returns something very strange sometimes). I check it does not work with window functions :\
I think I give up with that damned thing and will ask vendor to help.
Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Comment: @Pruntoff . . . Not a good reason, but a valid reason.  I updated the answer.  You should consider finding some other ways to pass queries to the database.  I share your frustration.